# Rust: Flattening nested struct to Vec<T>

Tags: functional-programming, rust, immutability

I have a struct which nests other structs like following:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Rankings {
    conferences: Vec<Conference>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Conference {
    divisions: Vec<Division>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Division {
    teams: Vec<Team>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Team {
    name: String,
    market: String,
}
```

What I want to do is converting a `Rankings` instance to `Vec<Team>`. Here's my solution:

```
fn main() {
    let mut rankings = Rankings {
        conferences: vec![
            Conference {
                divisions: vec![
                    Division {
                        teams: vec![
                            Team {
                                name: String::from("Raptors"),
                                market: String::from("Toronto"),
                            },
                            Team {
                                name: String::from("Knicks"),
                                market: String::from("New York"),
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    Division {
                        teams: vec![
                            Team {
                                name: String::from("Bucks"),
                                market: String::from("Milwaukee"),
                            },
                            Team {
                                name: String::from("Cavaliers"),
                                market: String::from("Cleveland"),
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    };

    println!("- rankings:\n{:#?}\n", rankings);

    let mut raw_teams: Vec<Vec<Vec<Team>>> = rankings
        .conferences
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|c| c.divisions.iter_mut().map(|d| d.teams.clone()).collect())
        .collect();

    println!("- raw_teams:\n{:#?}\n", raw_teams);

    let flattened_teams = raw_teams
        .iter_mut()
        .fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, val| {
            acc.append(val);
            acc
        })
        .iter_mut()
        .fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, val| {
            acc.append(val);
            acc
        });

    println!("- flattened_teams:\n{:#?}\n", flattened_teams);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58307f8e83dcea162f49f8e483b47c49)

First, I converted `Rankings` to `Vec<Vec<Vec<Team>>>` using `iter_mut()` and `map()`, then flattened `Vec<Vec<Vec<Team>>>` to `Vec<Team>` using `iter_mut()` and `fold()`.

But I just wrote that code avoiding compile errors, which mean the code could be refactored better using idiomatic patterns. I think I might overuse mutability, and two conversion process can be simplified using appropriate iterator functions. Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to use `iter_mut()` on `conferences`, as you never change the original `rankings`. As we `clone` the teams later, we can simply use

```
let mut raw_teams: Vec<Vec<Vec<Team>>> = rankings
    .conferences
    .iter()
    .map(|c| c.divisions.iter().map(|d| d.teams.clone()).collect())
    .collect();
```

Now that we have a `Vec<Vec<Vec<Team>>`, we can call [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```
let flattened_teams: Vec<Team> = raw_teams.into_iter().flatten().flatten().collect();
```

I used `into_iter()` as your original code left `raw_teams` empty.

However, we can skip `raw_teams` entirely if we use [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) instead of `map(…).flatten()`:

```
let flattened_teams: Vec<Team> = rankings
    .conferences
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|c| &c.divisions) // need to borrow due to iter()
    .flat_map(|d| &d.teams)     // need to borrow due to iter()
    .cloned()                   // clone the elements
    .collect();
```

If we don't want to borrow, we can of course just move everything into `flattened_teams` by simply removing `cloned()` and `&`:

```
let flattened_teams : Vec<Team> = rankings
    .conferences
    .into_iter()
    .flat_map(|c| c.divisions)
    .flat_map(|d| d.teams)
    .collect()
```

None of these functions use `mut`.

Comment: Note you can move the `cloned()` outside, right before the `collect()`.

Comment: Edited, @JayDepp, as it makes both variants symmetric.